# After SPD Reusable workflow imported in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I made a simple reusable workflow in SharePoint Designer. Which sends an email and then sets the WF status to "Completed".

Imported in Visual Studio 2010.

I added a CreateTask1 before the email activity in Visual Studio's version and then redeployed it.

Now I expect the workflow to be complete when the task is completed. How ever the workflow still sets to complete once the email is sent.

Any ideas what am I missing here please?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an OnTaskChanged activity after your CreateTask1. Wrap that inside of a while activity. Then, you have to check the status of the task in your code.

Here is the code behind:

```
public bool taskNotComplete = true;
public SPWorkflowTaskProperties onTaskChanged1_AfterProperties1 = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTaskProperties();

private void OnTaskChanged(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
{
    if (onTaskChanged1_AfterProperties1.PercentComplete == 100)
    {
        // set the while activity condition field
        this.taskNotComplete = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried to post a pic of my workflow designer here. But, since I am a noob, it wouldn't let me yet.